# Google Sitelinks Search Box

Tags: search, seo

For some reason, a search for our company name (“[hometalk](http://bit.ly/1Ef4dDg)”) does not produce the search box in the results (even though we do have sitelinks).

We are adding schema markup as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch), but we're not sure about:

Will adding the code make the search bar appear (or at least increase the chances), or is it only going to change the functionality of the search box (to on-site search) for results that are already showing a search bar?

Answer (score 0):

It is only going to change the functionality of the search box (to on-site search) for results that are already showing a search bar.

As stated here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch

> **Search box not displaying?** The sitelinks search box appears only for navigational queries and when relevant for users. Google
>   algorithms use a variety of factors to determine when the box appears,
>   including the information on the site and different types of
>   navigational queries from Search users.